# What's the meaning of grad_ys of tf.gradients?

Tags: tensorflow

[The doc describes like this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients):

> `grad_ys` is a list of tensors of the same length as `ys` that holds
>   the initial gradients for each y in `ys`.  When `grad_ys` is None,
>   we fill in a tensor of '1's of the shape of y for each y in `ys`.  A
>   user can provide their own initial `grad_ys` to compute the
>   derivatives using a different initial gradient for each y (e.g., if
>   one wanted to weight the gradient differently for each value in   each
>   y).

What does it mean "initial gradients" and "compute the derivatives using a different initial gradient"?

Comment: Does this link answer your question? (if not, I'll remove the dupe flag)

Comment: Yes, it is what I want.